# What is the difference between an function and functional?

Tags: functional-analysis, functions

Can someone give an example that would point out the difference between a function and a functional in a very simple way?

Comment: Usually functional is just a function with range $\mathbb R$

Comment: Have you read the wiki? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_(mathematics)

Comment: @AdamMarcik   Difference in a simple way is function takes a scalar as input and scalar as output and functional takes a function as input and scalar as output. This is very simple way to start thinking.

Answer (score 7):

In the context of functional analysis, a functional is a function from a vector space to its base field (usually $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$). In many important cases they are linear, but this is not always the case. In the context of normed vector spaces or more generally topological vector spaces, they are also often continuous, but again this is not always the case.

Much less commonly, people use the word "functional" to refer to any function that takes another function as an argument. But this is never the meaning in the context of functional analysis.

Comment: you missed out linear.

Comment: @user24142 That was deliberate; "nonlinear functionals" are quite common objects. If you want linear, you should say linear. But since you've pointed this out, I've remarked on it.